# F# XML Generation in .NET Core: XmlSerializer or XmlProvider

Tags: xml, f#, serialization, .net-core

I am working on SEPA XML generator in F#.

I developed two solutions that are roughly equivalent, one relies on the `XmlSerializer` while the other relies on `XmlProvider`, I am wondering what is the most idiomatic one?

Using the `XmlSerializer`:

```
module SepaConversion.SepaXmlA

open System
open System.Collections.ObjectModel
open System.IO
open System.Xml.Serialization
open SepaConversion.Models
open SepaConversion.Common


[<AutoOpen>]
module Serialization =

    [<CLIMutable>]
    [<XmlRoot(ElementName="InitgPty")>]
    type InitiatingParty = {
        [<XmlElement(ElementName="Nm")>]
        Name: string
    }

    [<CLIMutable>]
    [<XmlRoot(ElementName="GrpHdr")>]
    type GroupHeader = {
        [<XmlElement(ElementName="MsgId")>]
        MessageId: string

        [<XmlElement(ElementName="CreDtTm")>]
        CreationDateTime: string

        [<XmlElement(ElementName="NbOfTxs")>]
        TransactionCount: string

        [<XmlElement(ElementName="CtrlSum")>]
        ControlSum: string

        [<XmlElement(ElementName="InitgPty")>]
        InitiatingParty: InitiatingParty
    }

    [<CLIMutable>]
    [<XmlRoot(ElementName="SvcLvl")>]
    type ServiceLevel = {
        [<XmlElement(ElementName="Cd")>]
        Code: string
    }

    [<CLIMutable>]
    [<XmlRoot(ElementName="PmtTpInf")>]
    type PaymentTypeInformation = {

        [<XmlElement(ElementName="InstrPrty")>]
        InstructionPriority: string

        [<XmlElement(ElementName="SvcLvl")>]
        ServiceLevel: ServiceLevel
    }

    [<CLIMutable>]
    [<XmlRoot(ElementName="Dbtr")>]
    type Debtor = {
        [<XmlElement(ElementName="Nm")>]
        Name: string
    }

    [<CLIMutable>]
    [<XmlRoot(ElementName="Id")>]
    type AccountId = {
        [<XmlElement(ElementName="IBAN")>]
        Iban: string
    }

    [<CLIMutable>]
    [<XmlRoot(ElementName="DbtrAcct")>]
    type DebtorAccount = {
        [<XmlElement(ElementName="Id")>]
        AccountId: AccountId

        [<XmlElement(ElementName="Ccy")>]
        Currency: string
    }

    [<CLIMutable>]
    [<XmlRoot(ElementName="FinInstnId")>]
    type FinancialInstitutionId = {
        [<XmlElement(ElementName="BIC")>]
        Bic: string
    }

    [<CLIMutable>]
    [<XmlRoot(ElementName="DbtrAgt")>]
    type DebtorAgent = {
        [<XmlElement(ElementName="FinInstnId")>]
        FinancialInstitutionId: FinancialInstitutionId
    }

    [<CLIMutable>]
    [<XmlRoot(ElementName="PmtId")>]
    type PaymentIdentification = {
        [<XmlElement(ElementName="EndToEndId")>]
        EndToEndId: string
    }

    [<CLIMutable>]
    [<XmlRoot(ElementName="InstdAmt")>]
    type InstructedAmount = {
        [<XmlAttribute(AttributeName="Ccy")>]
        Currency: string
        [<XmlText>]
        Amount: string
    }

    [<CLIMutable>]
    [<XmlRoot(ElementName="Amt")>]
    type Amount = {
        [<XmlElement(ElementName="InstdAmt")>]
        InstructedAmount: InstructedAmount
    }

    [<CLIMutable>]
    [<XmlRoot(ElementName="CdtrAgt")>]
    type CreditorAgent = {
        [<XmlElement(ElementName="FinInstnId")>]
        FinancialInstitutionId: FinancialInstitutionId
    }

    [<CLIMutable>]
    [<XmlRoot(ElementName="Cdtr")>]
    type Creditor = {
        [<XmlElement(ElementName="Nm")>]
        Name: string
    }

    [<CLIMutable>]
    [<XmlRoot(ElementName="CdtrAcct")>]
    type CreditorAccount = {
        [<XmlElement(ElementName="Id")>]
        AccountId: AccountId
    }

    [<CLIMutable>]
    [<XmlRoot(ElementName="RmtInf")>]
    type RemittanceInformation = {
        [<XmlElement(ElementName="Ustrd")>]
        Unstructured: string
    }

    [<CLIMutable>]
    [<XmlRoot(ElementName="CdtTrfTxInf")>]
    type CreditTransferTransactionInformation = {
        [<XmlElement(ElementName="PmtId")>]
        PaymentIdentification: PaymentIdentification

        [<XmlElement(ElementName="Amt")>]
        Amount: Amount

        [<XmlElement(ElementName="CdtrAgt")>]
        CreditorAgent: CreditorAgent

        [<XmlElement(ElementName="Cdtr")>]
        Creditor: Creditor

        [<XmlElement(ElementName="CdtrAcct")>]
        CreditorAccount: CreditorAccount

        [<XmlElement(ElementName="RmtInf")>]
        RemittanceInformation: RemittanceInformation
    }

    [<CLIMutable>]
    [<XmlRoot(ElementName="PmtInf")>]
    type PaymentInformation = {
        [<XmlElement(ElementName="PmtInfId")>]
        PaymentInformationId: string

        [<XmlElement(ElementName="PmtMtd")>]
        PaymentMethod: string 

        [<XmlElement(ElementName="NbOfTxs")>]
        TransactionCount: string

        [<XmlElement(ElementName="CtrlSum")>]
        ControlSum: string

        [<XmlElement(ElementName="PmtTpInf")>]
        PaymentTypeInformation: PaymentTypeInformation 

        [<XmlElement(ElementName="ReqdExctnDt")>]
        RequestedExecutionDate: string

        [<XmlElement(ElementName="Dbtr")>]
        Debtor: Debtor 

        [<XmlElement(ElementName="DbtrAcct")>]
        DebtorAccount: DebtorAccount

        [<XmlElement(ElementName="DbtrAgt")>]
        DebtorAgent: DebtorAgent 

        [<XmlElement(ElementName="ChrgBr")>]
        ChargeBearer: string 

        [<XmlElement(ElementName="CdtTrfTxInf")>]
        CreditTransferTransactionInformation: CreditTransferTransactionInformation[]  
    }

    [<CLIMutable>]
    [<XmlRoot(ElementName="CstmrCdtTrfInitn")>]
    type CustomerCreditTransferInitialization = {
        [<XmlElement(ElementName="GrpHdr")>]
        GroupHeader: GroupHeader 

        [<XmlElement(ElementName="PmtInf")>]
        PaymentInformation: PaymentInformation 
    }

    [<CLIMutable>]
    [<XmlRoot(ElementName="Document", Namespace="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03")>]
    type Document = {
        [<XmlElement(ElementName="CstmrCdtTrfInitn")>]
        CustomerCreditTransferInitialization: CustomerCreditTransferInitialization 
    }

[<AutoOpen>]
module private Impl = 

    [<Literal>]
    let TransferAdvicePaymentMethod = "TRF"

    [<Literal>]
    let SepaServiceCode = "SEPA"

    [<Literal>]
    let HighInstructionPriority = "HIGH"

    [<Literal>]
    let DebtorChargeBearer = "SLEV"

    let createAmount (amount: decimal) currency = {
        InstructedAmount = {
            Currency = currency
            Amount = amount |> string
        }
    }

    let createPaymentIdentification id = {
        EndToEndId = id
    }

    let createCreditorAgent bic = {
        FinancialInstitutionId = {
            Bic = bic
        }
    }

    let createCreditor name = {
        Name = name
    }

    let createCreditorAccount iban = {
        AccountId = {
            Iban = iban
        }
    }

    let createRemittanceInformation reason = {
        Unstructured = reason
    }

    let createInitiatingParty name : InitiatingParty = {
        Name = name
    }

    let createDebtorAccount iban currency = {
        AccountId = {
            Iban = iban
        }
        Currency = currency
    }

    let createDebtorAgent bic : DebtorAgent = {
        FinancialInstitutionId = {
            Bic = bic
        }
    }

    let createGroupHeader (creationDateTime: DateTimeOffset) information = {
        MessageId = newHexGuid()
        CreationDateTime = creationDateTime.ToString("o")
        TransactionCount = information.CreditTransactions.Count |> string
        ControlSum = information.CreditTransactions
                     |> Seq.map (fun x -> x.Amount)
                     |> Seq.sum
                     |> string
        InitiatingParty = createInitiatingParty information.Debtor.Name
    }

    let createCreditTransferTransactionInformation (creditTransactions : ReadOnlyCollection<SepaCreditTransactionInformation>) currency =
        creditTransactions
        |> Seq.map(fun x ->
        {
            PaymentIdentification = createPaymentIdentification (newHexGuid())
            Amount = createAmount x.Amount currency
            CreditorAgent = createCreditorAgent x.Bic
            Creditor = createCreditor x.Name
            CreditorAccount = createCreditorAccount x.Iban
            RemittanceInformation = createRemittanceInformation x.Reason
        })
        |> Seq.toArray

    let createPaymentInformation messageId (requestedExecutionDate: DateTime) information creditTransferTransactionInformation = {
            PaymentInformationId = messageId
            PaymentMethod = TransferAdvicePaymentMethod
            TransactionCount = information.CreditTransactions.Count |> string
            ControlSum = information.CreditTransactions
                         |> Seq.map (fun x -> x.Amount)
                         |> Seq.sum
                         |> string
            PaymentTypeInformation = {
                InstructionPriority = HighInstructionPriority
                ServiceLevel = {
                    Code = SepaServiceCode
                }
            }
            RequestedExecutionDate = requestedExecutionDate.ToString("o")
            Debtor = {
                Name = information.Debtor.Name
            }
            DebtorAccount = createDebtorAccount information.Debtor.Iban information.Currency 
            DebtorAgent = createDebtorAgent information.Debtor.Bic
            ChargeBearer = DebtorChargeBearer
            CreditTransferTransactionInformation = creditTransferTransactionInformation
        }


let generateSepaXml (information: SepaInformation) =

    let creationTime = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow
    let groupHeader = createGroupHeader creationTime information
    let requestedExecutionDate = creationTime.UtcDateTime.AddDays(1.0)

    let creditTransferTransactionInformation = createCreditTransferTransactionInformation
                                                   information.CreditTransactions
                                                   information.Currency

    let paymentInformation = createPaymentInformation
                                 groupHeader.MessageId
                                 requestedExecutionDate
                                 information
                                 creditTransferTransactionInformation

    let document = {
        CustomerCreditTransferInitialization = {
            GroupHeader = groupHeader
            PaymentInformation = paymentInformation
        }
    }

    let xmlSerializer = XmlSerializer(typeof<Document>)
    use stringWriter = new StringWriter()
    xmlSerializer.Serialize(stringWriter, document)
    stringWriter |> string
```

Using the `XmlProvider` with a XSD file: [`pain.001.001.03.xsd`](https://github.com/perrich/sepawriter/blob/master/SepaWriter/Xsd/pain.001.001.03.xsd):

```
module SepaConversion.SepaXmlB

open System
open FSharp.Data
open SepaConversion.Models
open SepaConversion.Common


[<AutoOpen>]
module private Impl = 

    type Sepa = XmlProvider<Schema="pain.001.001.03.xsd", EmbeddedResource="SepaConversion, pain.001.001.03.xsd">

    [<Literal>]
    let TransferAdvicePaymentMethod = "TRF"

    [<Literal>]
    let SepaServiceCode = "SEPA"

    [<Literal>]
    let HighInstructionPriority = "HIGH"

    [<Literal>]
    let SepaChargeBearer = "SLEV"

    let sepaServiceLevel =
        Sepa.SvcLvl(cd = Some SepaServiceCode,
                    prtry = None)

    let createInitiatingParty name =
        Sepa.InitgPty(nm = Some name,
                      pstlAdr = None,
                      id = None,
                      ctryOfRes = None,
                      ctctDtls = None)

    let emptyAuthorizations = [||]

    let paymentTypeInformation =
        Sepa.PmtTpInf(instrPrty = Some HighInstructionPriority,
                      svcLvl = Some sepaServiceLevel,
                      lclInstrm = None,
                      ctgyPurp = None)

    let createFinancialInstitutionId bic =
        Sepa.FinInstnId(bic = Some bic,
                        clrSysMmbId = None,
                        nm = None,
                        pstlAdr = None,
                        othr = None)

    let createIbanId iban =
         Sepa.Id2(iban = Some iban, othr = None)

    let createDebtorAgent bic =
        Sepa.DbtrAgt(finInstnId = createFinancialInstitutionId bic,
                     brnchId = None)

    let createDebtorAccount iban currency  =
        Sepa.DbtrAcct(id = createIbanId iban,
                      tp = None,
                      ccy = Some currency,
                      nm = None)

    let createDebtor name =
        Sepa.Dbtr(nm = Some name,
                  pstlAdr = None,
                  id = None,
                  ctryOfRes = None,
                  ctctDtls = None)

    let createGroupHeader messageId creationTime (transactionCount : int32) controlSum initiatingParty =
        Sepa.GrpHdr(msgId = messageId, 
                    creDtTm = creationTime,
                    authstns = emptyAuthorizations,
                    nbOfTxs = (transactionCount |> string),
                    ctrlSum = Some controlSum,
                    initgPty = initiatingParty,
                    fwdgAgt = None)

    let createPaymentId id =
        Sepa.PmtId(instrId = None,
                   endToEndId = id)

    let createInstructedAmount amount currency =
        Sepa.InstdAmt(ccy = currency,
                      value = amount)

    let createAmount amount currency =
        Sepa.Amt(instdAmt = Some (createInstructedAmount amount currency),
                 eqvtAmt = None)

    let createCreditorAgent bic =
        Sepa.CdtrAgt(finInstnId = createFinancialInstitutionId bic,
                     brnchId = None)

    let createCreditorAccount iban  =
        Sepa.CdtrAcct(id = createIbanId iban,
                      tp = None,
                      ccy = None,
                      nm = None)

    let createCreditor name =
        Sepa.Cdtr(nm = Some name,
                  pstlAdr = None,
                  id = None,
                  ctryOfRes = None,
                  ctctDtls = None)

    let createRemittanceInformation reason =
        Sepa.RmtInf(ustrds = [| reason |], strds = null)

    let createCreditTransferTransactionInformation creditTransaction currency =
        Sepa.CdtTrfTxInf(pmtId = createPaymentId (newHexGuid()),
                         pmtTpInf = None,
                         amt = createAmount creditTransaction.Amount currency,
                         xchgRateInf = None,
                         chrgBr = None,
                         chqInstr = None,
                         ultmtDbtr = None,
                         intrmyAgt1 = None,
                         intrmyAgt1Acct = None,
                         intrmyAgt2 = None,
                         intrmyAgt2Acct = None,
                         intrmyAgt3 = None,
                         intrmyAgt3Acct = None,
                         cdtrAgt = Some (createCreditorAgent creditTransaction.Bic),
                         cdtrAgtAcct = None,
                         cdtr = Some (createCreditor creditTransaction.Name),
                         cdtrAcct = Some (createCreditorAccount creditTransaction.Iban),
                         ultmtCdtr = None,
                         instrForCdtrAgts = [||],
                         instrForDbtrAgt = None,
                         purp = None,
                         rgltryRptgs = [||],
                         tax = None,
                         rltdRmtInfs = [||],
                         rmtInf = Some (createRemittanceInformation creditTransaction.Reason))

    let createCreditTransferTransactionInformationArray creditTransactions currency =
        creditTransactions
        |> Seq.map(fun x -> createCreditTransferTransactionInformation x currency)
        |> Seq.toArray

    let createPaymentInformation messageId (transactionCount: int32) controlSum requestedExecutionDate information =
         Sepa.PmtInf(pmtInfId = messageId,
                     pmtMtd = TransferAdvicePaymentMethod,
                     btchBookg = None,
                     nbOfTxs = Some (transactionCount |> string),
                     ctrlSum = Some controlSum,
                     pmtTpInf = Some paymentTypeInformation,
                     reqdExctnDt = requestedExecutionDate,
                     poolgAdjstmntDt = None,
                     dbtr = createDebtor information.Debtor.Name,
                     dbtrAcct = createDebtorAccount information.Debtor.Iban information.Currency,
                     dbtrAgt = createDebtorAgent information.Debtor.Bic,
                     dbtrAgtAcct = None,
                     ultmtDbtr = None,
                     chrgBr = Some SepaChargeBearer,
                     chrgsAcct = None,
                     chrgsAcctAgt = None,
                     cdtTrfTxInfs = createCreditTransferTransactionInformationArray
                                        information.CreditTransactions
                                        information.Currency)

    let createCustomerCreditTransferInitialization groupHeader paymentInformation =
        new Sepa.CstmrCdtTrfInitn(grpHdr = groupHeader,
                                  pmtInfs = [| paymentInformation |])

    let createDocument (customerCreditTransferInitialization: Sepa.CstmrCdtTrfInitn) =
        Sepa.Document(customerCreditTransferInitialization)

let generateSepaXml information =
    let messageId = newHexGuid()
    let creationTime = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow
    let requestedExecutionDate = creationTime.UtcDateTime.AddDays(1.0)
    let transactionCount = information.CreditTransactions.Count
    let controlSum = information.CreditTransactions
                     |> Seq.map (fun x -> x.Amount)
                     |> Seq.sum

    let initiatingParty = createInitiatingParty information.Debtor.Name

    let groupHeader = createGroupHeader
                          messageId
                          creationTime
                          transactionCount
                          controlSum
                          initiatingParty

    let paymentInformation = createPaymentInformation
                                 messageId
                                 transactionCount
                                 controlSum
                                 requestedExecutionDate
                                 information

    let customerCreditTransferInitialization = createCustomerCreditTransferInitialization
                                                   groupHeader
                                                   paymentInformation
    let document = createDocument customerCreditTransferInitialization

    document.XElement |> string
```

The `XmlProvider` way seems more FP-ish and does not require to maintain a set of record types to generation the XML. However, the ctors generated by the provider are quite lengthy, I was surprised that I had to fill up everything and I was expecting that additional ctors would be generated of the fly, for example setting `None` option arguments so that not everything needs to be filled which would have made the experience a bit more convenient. Also it's a bit more cryptic in a sense that the maintainer has to know the meaning of each xml tags.

Surely I can add more wrapper functions to add some meanings, or literals /constants like:

```
[<Literal>]
let private PaymentMethod = "TRF"

[<Literal>]
let private SepaCode = "SEPA"

[<Literal>]
let private InstructionPriority = "NORM"
```

Not sure if it's just a matter of taste, or if there is a real and clear benefit using one method over the other.

[EDIT]

Another issue with the `XmlProvider`, the need to copy to the output the schema file when building. Embedded resource only works xml samples =/

Another cons for `XmlSerializer`, it cannot serializer internal classes without a lof trickeries.